# Simple python code with datetime, datetime operation and datetime formating, I would like to make it more concise

Tags: python

I am sure there will be a way to make this code simpler, can someone take a look?

Basically what it does is:

1. get `now` and `a week ago from now`
2. then format it to utc (i.e. `2020-02-04T23:18:00Z`)
3. to enter in boto3 command as parameters

```py
import datetime

end_time = datetime.datetime.now()
start_time = end_time - datetime.timedelta(days=7)

end_time = end_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
start_time = start_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
```

Comment: Can you explain what and why you think this could be made simpler?

Answer (score 1):

This is already about as simple as it can get.

The only real simplification would be to use [`datetime.datetime.isoformat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.isoformat), and make it into a simple function (with typing, default arguments and a doc-string). To enable reusing this function by importing it in another file, you can put the rest of the code behind a `if __name__ == "__main__:`-guard

```
import datetime
import typing

def get_timestamps(
    end_time: datetime.datetime = None,
    delta: datetime.timedelta = datetime.timedelta(days=7),
) -> typing.Tuple[str, str]:
    """ < docstring> """
    if end_time is None:
        end_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    start_time = end_time - delta
    return start_time.isoformat(), end_time.iso_format()

if __name__ == "__main__:
    end_time, start_time = get_timestamps()
```

if the `iso_format` is not what you need, you can start already by making the time format into a variable:

```
datetime_format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ"
end_time = end_time.strftime(datetime_format)
start_time = start_time.strftime(datetime_format)
```

This serves both as an explanation what that weird-looking string is, and prevents silly typological mistakes causing different formatting of the start and end time

BTW, this does not include the timezone info. You need to add a `%z` for that